# Onchange Event is getting Error. ReferenceError in function

Tags: javascript

I have created the table with calculation logic. I used onchange method, but I got a ReferenceError in my function. Please help me find out where I made a mistake or where I need to change the code.

My Function :

```
function calculates()

{

 var a = document.forms["MyForm"]["basicSeat"].value;

 var b = a * document.forms["MyForm"]["basicSeatMrc"].value;

 document.forms["MyForm"]["basicSeatMrcTotal"].value = b;

 var c = document.forms["MyForm"]["crsSeat"].value;

 var d = c * document.forms["MyForm"]["crsSeatMrc"].value;

 document.forms["MyForm"]["crsSeatMrcTotal"].value = d;

 document.forms["MyForm"]["totalMrc"].value = document.forms["MyForm"]["basicSeatMrcTotal"].value + document.forms["MyForm"]["crsSeatMrcTotal"].value;

}


My Table Code :

html = "<form name='MyForm'><table class='addrtable' border ='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>";

 html += "<tr><td valign='top'>";

 html += "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'><b><td>Seat Type</td><td>Quantity</td><td>MRC</td><td>NRC</td><td>Ext. MRC</td><td>Ext. NRC</td><b></tr>";

 html += "<tr><td>Basic Seats</td><td><input type='text' id='basicSeat' name='basicSeat' onchange='javascript:calculates();' /></td><td><input type='text' id='basicSeatMrc' name='basicSeatMrc' value='17.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='basicSeatNrc' name='basicSeatNrc' value='59.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='basicSeatMrcTotal' name='basicSeatMrcTotal' value='0.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='basicSeatNrcTotal' name='basicSeatNrcTotal' value='0.00'/></td></tr>";

 html += "<tr><td>Conference Room Seats</td><td><input type='text' id='crsSeat' name='crsSeat' onchange='javascript:calculates();' /></td><td><input type='text' id='crsSeatMrc' name='crsSeatMrc' value='22.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='crsSeatNrc' name='crsSeatNrc' value='59.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='crsSeatMrcTotal' name='crsSeatMrcTotal' value='0.00'/></td><td><input type='text' id='crsSeatTrcTotal' name='crsSeatTrcTotal' value='0.00'/></td></tr>";

html+="</tr></table></form>";
```

Comment: Can you please provide more context to your error? What is getting a `ReferenceError`

Comment: This type of errors generally appears when calling an undeclared function ... Are you sure you encapsulated the function declaration in `<script type="text/javascript">function calculates() { .... } </script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is `TypeError: document.forms.MyForm.totalMrc is undefined`. That means there is no `input` with id `totalMrc` in your form.